# $R$ a ring, $\alpha,\beta\in R$, prove $\beta \in \frak{p}^n \setminus \frak{p}^{n+1}$ and $\alpha\beta \in \frak{p}^{n+1}$implies$\alpha\in\frak{p}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Question: Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, and let $\frak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $R$. Take any element $\beta$ such that $\beta \in \frak{p}^n$ and $\beta \notin \frak{p}^{n+1}$. Let $\alpha$ be any element of $R$ such that $\alpha \beta \in \frak{p}^{n+1}$. Does that imply that $\alpha \in \frak{p}$?

Context: I am reading some online notes about algebraic number theory, and in the middle of a proof the author used this implication. The ring $R$ happened to be some ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$, so if some additional assumptions (integral domain) are needed on $R$ that is ok too. So I was trying to prove this but I can't see any progress.

Intuitively this seems true, for example if $R$ is a PID.

Comment: For the ring of integers of a number field and $ab\ne 0$ it is because of the unique factorization of $(b),(ab),(a)$ in product of maximal ideals. Otherwise, if $a\not \in p$ then $a$ is a unit of $R_p=(R-p)^{-1}R$ thus $(ab,p^{n+1})=(b,p^{n+1})$  in $R_p$.

Comment: Can I check if I have understood your comment: So if $ab \in p^{n+1}$, then $(ab, p^{n+1}) = (p^{n+1})$ in $R_p$ and hence $(b, p^{n+1}) = (p^{n+1}) \in R_p$, but this is a contradiction because $b \notin p^{n+1}$?

Comment: I see, I totally overlooked that extra check :O